# Passing arguments on symfony 4 for UserProvider:__construct

Tags: doctrine, cas, symfony4

I am using Symfony 4 with doctrine. The problem is that I can not use doctrine outside of the controllers directly.

In a bundle called prayno casauth bundle (https://github.com/PRayno/CasAuthBundle), I want to access to doctrine to get the roles from the database.

For that, I must call the entity manager. I did it the way below but I have an error:

```
Too few arguments to function CasUserProvider::__construct(), 
0 passed in and exactly 1 expected.
```

The problem is that I do not know where and how to pass an argument.

```
class CasUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface { 

private $em; 
public function __construct(EntityManager $em) {
 $this->em = $em; 
}
```